# How to correctly set the sort mode of a query with Bodybuilder?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, bodybuilder.js

I've picked up a project that uses [Bodybuilder.js](https://bodybuilder.js.org) for queries to ELK and I am struggling to figure out how to format the query with Bodybuilder. I should note that I've tested this same query in other languages and it worked fine.

As I had written it previously it was:

```
"sort" {
    "duration": {
        "order": "desc",
        "mode": "max"
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell from the [docs](https://bodybuilder.js.org/docs/#sort) (end of the last example) it should be written something like:

```
.sort([{ "duration": { "order": "desc", "mode": "max" }}])
```

but this query is giving me an error from the server. I should note that:

```
.sort("duration", "desc")
```

on the other hand does not give an error, but does not give the desired result, just to clear up any concern about the key itself.

Information on this is a bit sparse but hopefully someone who's ran into this before can offer some help as the docs aren't giving me more than I mentioned and that's not working.